# Ryzen + Gigabyte ubuntu start error

Tags: boot, support

I can't start ubuntu and mint, because it fails with the error:

> Unexpected IRQ trap at vector 07

I'v tried ubuntu 17.04 and mint 18.3 (based on ubuntu 16.04).

My processor: AMD Ryzen 1500x
My motherboard: ga-ab350m-d3h

I tried to update my bios from F1 version to F3 one, but it didn't help me.
Also I didn't find `acpi` in my bios.

Any ideas?

Comment: Thank guys! The problem solved by installing ubuntu 16.04.1

Answer (score 0):

As per [this comment](https://askubuntu.com/posts/951358/timeline#comment_1515581), it seems that the solution to the issue in your question is to "*install Ubuntu 16.04.1*" ...

Credits: [Соколов](https://askubuntu.com/users/731276/%d0%a1%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2) ... (note: quite challenging user name to type on a BE-keyboard ... lucky there was copy/paste ...)

Comment: You're too late: I found the same solution for an hour before you. PS: I am Russian